# How to create a Json having many parent and child relationship dynamically in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a parent name and its child name. I can represent this data in json. But, for the next iteration, I need to check if the parent name key already exists. If it exists, add the child to the same parent. Otherwise create a new parent and child node. Can anyone suggest me the exact way to create this kind of json in javascript.

```
    {
    "name": "Mapping",
    "Process": [{
            "name": "process-1",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "child-1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "child-2"
                }
            ]
            }]
}
```

Comment: FYI the object you have there is invalid; there's no key on the parent array.

Comment: It's a bit confusing if you will create an array or a map object.

Comment: your json is not right there is no key in it for parent can yo edit your json please

Comment: Now, I think my json object is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
(pseudocode)

```
if ((object.name === undefined)){//check if the parent has the name key
  //add child to the parent
} else {
  // create the object, adding a child, and the child's name
}
```

Basically, you can check to see if something exists by accessing it.

Comment: Btw, your JSON is also invalid at the moment. google "json validator" and run it through to look at the errors!